# What is the Index of Sustainable Economic Welfare (ISEW)?

Tags: defining-sustainability, economics

What is the Index of Sustainable Economic Welfare (ISEW) about? Does it measure the relation between energy and well being? Or does it have other parameters?

Comment: Some info here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_Sustainable_Economic_Welfare